# I am unable to create entity or fetch list of entities due to stack overflow error on bi-directional @ManyToMany relationship SpringDataJPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a springboot application. I have 2 entity classes, Group and User. I also have @ManyToMany relationship defined in the Group class (Owning entity), and also in the User class, so that I can fetch all the groups a user belongs to. Unfortunately, I can't create a new group or a new user due to the following error;

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-09-09T20:29:22.606+00:00",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported"
}
```

When I try to fetch all groups a user belongs to by calling `user.get().getGroups();` I get a a stack overflow error

Note: Currently I have @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference in Group and User classes respectively. I also tried adding `@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")` on both classes, but this did not work either. Adding value parameter to @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference as demonstrated below did not work either. What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

This is my **Group** entity class

```
@Table(name = "`group`") // <- group is a reserved keyword in SQL
public class Group {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private String name;
    private Integer maximumMembers;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name = "group_user", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "group-member")
    private Set<User> groupMembers;
}
```

This is my **User** entity class

```
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private Long id;
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private String nickname;
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private String username; // <- Unique user's phone number
    private String password;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = ApplicationUserRole.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "role")
    private Set<ApplicationUserRole> roles;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groupMembers", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Group.class)
    @JsonBackReference(value = "user-group")
    private Set<Group> groups;
}
```

Minimal, Reproducible Example https://github.com/Java-Techie-jt/JPA-ManyToMany

Comment: I think you need to use referencedColumnName when you giving @JoinColumn .

@JoinColumn(name = "user_id",referencedColumnName = "id")

Comment: Is it mandatory? I thought this is normally optional.

Comment: How is the 415 connected? (Where is controller? Spring-data-rest?) Please try to make an [mre]

Comment: Use this https://github.com/Java-Techie-jt/JPA-ManyToMany as MRE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a permanent solution for this problem. For anyone else facing a similar problem, This is what I found. First, my entity classes had `@Data` Lombok annotation. I removed this because the `@Data` annotation has a tendency of almost always loading collections even if you have `FetchType.LAZY`.

You can read more about why you should't annotate your entity class with `@Data` here https://www.jpa-buddy.com/blog/lombok-and-jpa-what-may-go-wrong/

After removing this annotation, I removed `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` from both sides of the relationship(both entities). I then added `@Jsonignore` to the referencing side only(User class). This solves 2 things

1. Creating a group with a list of users works fine
2. Adding a list of users to a group works fine.

After this, we are left with one last problem. When we try to read a user from the api, we get a user without the associated list of groups they belong to, because we have `@JsonIgnore` on the user list. To solve this, I made the controller return a new object. So after fetching the user from my service, I map it to a new data transfer object, the I return this object in the controller.

From here I used `@JsonView` to filter my responses.

This is how my classes look, notice there is no `@Data` in annotations.

**Group**

```
@Builder
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "`group`") // <- group is a reserved keyword in SQL
public class Group {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Integer maximumMembers;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(name = "group_user",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @JsonView(UserViews.PublicUserDetails.class)
    private Set<User> groupMembers = new HashSet<>();

}
```

**User**

```
@Builder
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonView(UserViews.PublicUserDetails.class)
    private Long id;
    @JsonView(UserViews.PublicUserDetails.class)
    private String nickname;
    @JsonView(UserViews.PublicUserDetails.class)
    private String username; // <- Unique user's phone number
    private String password;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = ApplicationUserRole.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "role")
    @JsonView(UserViews.PublicUserDetails.class)
    private Set<ApplicationUserRole> roles;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groupMembers", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Group.class)
    private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Method fetching user in user controller

```
@GetMapping("/get-groups")
    public ResponseEntity<UserRequestResponseDTO> getWithGroups(@RequestParam(name = "userId") Long userId) {
        User user = userService.getWithGroups(userId);
        UserRequestResponseDTO response = UserRequestResponseDTO.builder()
                .nickname(user.getNickname())
                .username(user.getUsername())
                .groups(user.getGroups())
                .build();
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(response);
    }
```

Hopefully this helps someone